# How to export GitHub-flavored Markdown file as PDF?

Tags: github, pdf, export, markdown, render

I have some Markdown files in a GitHub repo. I need to export them to PDF. I could do this with a dedicated tool, but I actually like GitHub's rendering. I'm wondering: Is there a way to do either of the following?

- Get GitHub to render the content without all of its other surrounding UI elements (so that I can "print" the page to a PDF from my browser)
- Get GitHub to natively export the file to PDF?

Comment: PanWriter has a similar stylesheet: see https://panwriter.com/MANUAL.html#export-preview-to-pdf Or you could always edit GitHub's HTML in your browser's dev tools, remove the GUI there, and print what's left...